# Custom sort of search results

Tags: custom-list

I have a site with 4 lists, with the same column names, each list has over 4,000 items. Need to search all lists and display result sorted by column called CaseNumber in descending order. Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using content search webpart, your can write a query to limit your search result from the 4 lists only, this will be done by providing the URL's of the lists, content search webpart has sorting option as well, you should be able to see"CaseNumber" column in the list of fields, if you don't see your column, you have to create a managedfiled for that.

more detail can be found [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html)